# Drupal 7 database API 'clean' code

Tags: drupal

This code joins several tables together and then does a union. It is for a module that I am writing for a Drupal 7 site.

```
$query1 = db_select('field_data_field_short_title', 's');
$query1->join('node', 'n', 'n.nid = s.entity_id');
$query1->join('field_data_field_a_z', 'a', 'a.entity_id = n.nid');

$query1->addField('s', 'field_short_title_value');
$query1->addField('n', 'nid');
$query1->addField('a', 'field_a_z_value');

$query2 = db_select('field_data_field_short_title_alternative', 'h');
$query2->join('node', 'o', 'o.nid = h.entity_id');
$query2->join('field_data_field_a_z', 'z', 'z.entity_id = o.nid');

$query2->addField('h', 'field_short_title_alternative_value');
$query2->addField('o', 'nid');
$query2->addField('z', 'field_a_z_value');

$query1->union($query2);

$result = $query1->execute();
```

From looking at other examples of using Drupal's database API, I get the feeling there may be a 'cleaner' way of writing this. There is a lot of repetition in my code. Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. You might want to look at [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) though.

Answer (score -1):

If the query is not dynamically generated you should consider just writing the sql in db_query.   Db_select has more overhead.